# Does Idris have an equivalent to Agda's `_` expressions?

Tags: agda, dependent-type, theorem-proving, idris

In addition to having implicit arguments, Agda lets you omit the value of an explicit argument and replace it with a metavariable, denoted by the `_` character, whose value is then determined through the same procedure as implicit resolution.

Does Idris have a similar feature, or are implicit arguments the only way of introducing metavariables into programs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `_` in Idris as well.

```
import Data.Vect

foo : (n : Nat) -> Vect n a -> Vect n a
foo n xs = xs

bar : Vect 3 Nat
bar = foo _ [1, 2, 3]   -- works
```

Comment: Looks like I missed this, thought it was invalid because I had other syntax errors! Either way, it's not very clearly documented. Thanks!